# Wave superposition, is my textbook wrong?

Tags: electricity, waves, interference, superposition, textbook-erratum

Here's the question: Two coherent electromagnetic waves are incident simultaneously at some point in space. The intensity of each independent wave is $I_0$. What is the intensity of the superposition of these two waves if the phase difference is 2π?

Apparently the answer is $4I_0$, but I thought the superposition height of waves was just the sum of the individual heights.  What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets suppose the amplitude of each wave is $A$ and thus intensity will be $I_0 =A^2$.

After superposition amplitude of the resultant wave becomes $2A$.
but intensity becomes $I=(2A)^2$
Implies $I=4A^2 =4I_0$